# basic jquery install issue: why is the jquery library not loaded

Tags: jquery

I am brand new to jquery and trying to get it installed on a page following [this tutorial.](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) Based on that example, the head of my HTML document looks like this:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("test");
}
</script>

</head>
```

I would assume that this would trigger an alert box "test" when the page loads (showing that I sucessfully installed jquery) but this is not the case.  I am able to get to the URL from the google API in my script tag using a browser so there should not be a networking issue 'finding' jquery.

What am I missing?

Comment: u miss a `);` , maybe..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: Definitely missing the `)` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your error console, and it probably has an error saying there's an error regarding an expected semicolon, or unexpected end of the function. You're missing your closing parentheses at the end of the ready() function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("test");
});
</script>
```